# Преобразовать словарь в json или строку

Tags: python, json, requests

Я походу уже туплю(
Надо распарсить json файл

```
leads = requests.post(url_lead_short_validate, json=lead_send, verify=False, headers=headers)
lead_valid = leads.json()
print(lead_valid)


i = json.loads(lead_valid)
new_short = i['data']['mtsRequestId']
short = new_short.json
print(new_short)
```

и вот такой лог:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/FaCard/new_short_ful.py", line 60, in <module>
    i = json.loads(lead_valid)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

Пробовал вот так, не помогает:

```
i = json.loads(str(lead_valid))
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в `lead_valid` - словарь (о чем, кстати, и говорит текст ошибки: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict`), так что попробуйте сразу "добывать" из него `['data']['mtsRequestId']`:

```
leads = requests.post(url_lead_short_validate, json=lead_send, verify=False, headers=headers)
lead_valid = leads.json()
print(lead_valid)

# i = json.loads(lead_valid)
# new_short = i['data']['mtsRequestId']
# short = new_short.json

new_short = lead_valid['data']['mtsRequestId']
print(new_short)
```

Comment: Ну это, кстати, логично, что `leads.json()` отдаёт уже готовый `json`, который не надо загружать через `json.loads` )